# Facebook like button doesn't post on users timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-timeline

i added an like button to my page which were meant do display each like on the specific users timeline.

Although when the user clicks like, and confirms (since it's a new site) the "like" nothing happens except that it says on the like button on the page that "Name likes this". Nothing on the users Facebook timeline or in profile.

The Facebook debugger doesn't report any errors whatsoever. Which makes it hard to tell for me why it doesn't share on the timeline. So i don't know exactly what to do or correct right now.

Any insight from someone who has been in this spot would be appreciated.

```
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="MY_APP_ID" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.MY_URL.se/" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.MY_URL.se/folder/fbLike.png" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="MY_URL.se - PAGE TITLE" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="SITE_NAME" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="DESCRIPTION" />

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sv_SE/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.MY_URL.se/" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false" style="position: absolute; z-index:5; margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 335px;"></div>
```

Comment: You could try share button, which will post on user's timeline for sure

Comment: @Darvex - Yes, as fortunate for me (since the like seems to have been messed up) i can still share content with the Feed dialog (which is working as intended using the same App id). But still, the thing with the Like annoyes me. Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confirm doesn´t come for new sites, it usually comes if you aren´t using an app id (which is the case here), or if spammy behaviour is detected. Try using an app, just select it in the generator: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

This could be the solution, but to make it more visible, the user has to add a comment too.

Comment: So the Like button doesn't actually show the like in the Timeline? You are correct about the spam, i have spammed and removed lot's of content (during development/testing) using the Feed dialog. But by more and more different (hopefully) users that report "No spam site" this "spam-tag" will go away?

Comment: Go check your activity log, you should see the like there. Whether or not liking something shows up on the user’s timeline depends on different factors, like popularity of the site, how many spam reports it had, etc. (From your activity log, you should be able to force it to show on your timeline.)

Comment: @CBroe - Sadly it doesn't even show up on my activity log, not even in the stats for the app itself in the developer section. For example 4 people likes the site. Even though, it displays 0 likes in the app stats section..

Answer (score 0):

So, i have come to the conclusion that since the update to the "new" timeline in Facebook, an like with no attached comment will not be displayed in the users timeline/activity feed.

When the user includes an comment during the Like click, it will be shown (This is only based on theory, i haven't been able to actually confirm this yet).

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the page does not have the correct open graph tags and can be fixed by inspecting them here. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/